# Start stopped service because of dependency update

Tags: ubuntu, service, systemd

I have two systemd services: `postgresql.service` and `app.service`. `postgresql.service` is distribution provided (ubuntu 15.10) and `app.service` is written by myself.

Since `app` needs `postgresql`, the service looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start App

Requires=postgresql.service
After=postgresql.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/path/to/app
```

Now today postgresql got updated. Of course it restarted the `postgresql.service` after update automatically. But this killed my `app.service`, because it requires `postgresql`:

```
# systemctl status app
[...]
Apr 08 12:04:42 host systemd[1]: Stopping Start App...
Apr 08 12:04:42 host systemd[1]: Stopped Start App.
```

`Apr 08 12:04:42` is the time where the update of `postgresql` happened.

How can I change the `app.service` so that it does not simply get killed when `postgresql` restarts but (re)starts automatically then, too (only when it is enabled, of course)?

Or to ask it another way around: How can I configure `app.service` that it always automatically starts after `postgresql.service` when `app.service` is enabled? So basically a `systemctl start postgresql` first starts `postgresql` and then automatically `app`.

Comment: A solution is described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375091/how-to-get-my-systemd-service-restarted-when-its-dependency-is-upgraded

Answer (score 1):

I think systemd wants me to use `Wants` instead of `Requires`. From the manual:

> Requires=
>
> Configures requirement dependencies on other units. If this unit gets activated, the units listed here will be activated as well. If one of the other units gets deactivated or its activation fails, this unit will be deactivated. [...] Often, it is a better choice to use Wants= instead of Requires= in order to achieve a system that is more robust when dealing with failing services.

Now using `Wants` and this seems to be like what I really want a robust system dealing with failing services. So I do.

Comment: Good hint. But is this answer the solution to your problem? Does it work out this way?

Answer (score 0):

You could add `postgresql.service` to your services `WantedBy`

```
[Unit]
Description=Start App

Requires=postgresql.service
After=postgresql.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target postgresql.service

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/path/to/app
```

dont forget to `systemctl reenable app.service` after `systemctl daemon-reload` to let systemd create the new symlink