# start systemd service on start of requirement

Tags: service, systemd

I have a service which depends on mysql.service via `Requires=`. This is necessary, because the service crashes, if mysql is not available.

Executing `systemctl restart mysql` works fine. It stops my service first, restarts mysql and starts my service again.

How can I configure my unit, that it is also started again, if I run `systemctl stop mysql && systemctl start mysql`?

This is especially a problem during debian’s unattended-upgrades of mysql, because the update-process uses `stop`/`start` and not `restart`.

Comment: did you find a solution meanwhile? I have exactly the  same problem here. Is [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/769001/start-stopped-service-because-of-dependency-update?rq=1) maybe a similar one with the `Wants` solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

### new and better answer

Clearly i have not been reading well yesterday.
It seems your problem can easily be solved by adding `mysql.service` to  your services `WantedBy`under the `[Install]` section.

then after you reenable your service, it should be started whenever `mysql.service` is started, as long as your service is enabled

the result looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Requires=mysql.service
After=mysql.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target mysql.service
```

---

### my old answer for reference:

I don't know if it is possible to configure your unit to behave the way you want it to.

I have, however, solved similar problems by installing systemd drop-in files to modify the foreign unit, in your case `mysql.service`.

assuming your unit is `foo.service` you could create a `.conf` file in
`/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Wants=foo.service
Before=foo.service
```

this would cause systemd to try and start `foo.service` after every start of `mysql.service`

for completeness sake, and to quote systemd [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Description):

> In addition to /etc/systemd/system, the drop-in ".conf" files for system services can be placed in /usr/lib/systemd/system or /run/systemd/system directories. Drop-in files in /etc take precedence over those in /run which in turn take precedence over those in /usr/lib. Drop-in files under any of these directories take precedence over unit files wherever located. (Of course, since /run is temporary and /usr/lib is for vendors, it is unlikely drop-ins should be used in either of those places.)